# Rails when to use current_user in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I find myself relying on my `current_user` helper method often in controllers. However the more I use it the more I think I probably shouldn't be. Is this because my routes aren't as RESTful as they should be? Should I really be looking up `User.find(params[:user_id])` for any request where I find myself using current_user (especially in the context of ever opening up an API)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST is to do with the routes, ie how paths and parameters work together to determine which controller action handles a request etc.  That's got nothing to do with `current_user`.  `current_user` is looking in your **session** (which ultimately uses a cookie on the client's machine) to see who is currently logged in.

You would use `User.find(params[:user_id])` in a situation where the user of the website wants to do something with that specific User record (which might be their own but probably isn't).  it's got nothing to do with who is currently logged into your site.

EDIT:  you mention APIs at the end.  Generally, if an API does anything at all with the concept of a "current_user" then the current user would be the person who has **authenticated** via the API's access controls, whatever they would be, similar to the concept of somebody logging into the website, except that normally with an API you don't have the concept of staying logged in:  each API request would normally authenticate itself, if any authentication is required at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably correct in using `current_user` as much as you do. You don't want to pass the user ID through params and rely on that for security reasons.

Without seeing any of your code, I'll assume that you understand MVC to the extent that models should be fat, and controllers should be skinny. Therefore, using `current_user` with devise (I assume) often in controllers is necessary to get the current user's information.